# OpenRefine: Fill down with increasing counter

Tags: autofill, openrefine

Is it possible in OpenRefine to fill down blank cells with a counter instead of copying the top non-blank value?

In this example image:

[image: example open refine column with some cells filled with 1 and the other with blanks]

Or here the same example as typed text - image this as a column from top to bottom:

```
1
1
blank
1
blank
blank
blank
blank
blank
1
```

I would like to see the column filled as follows (again, imagine top to bottom):

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
```

Thanks, help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really simple. You have to:

1 Replace the blanks with something else, such as an "x"

2 Create a unique record for the entire dataset

3 Use this Jython script:

```
import itertools
data = row['record']['cells']['YOUR COLUMN NAME']['value']
x = itertools.count(2)

liste = []
for i, el in enumerate(data):
    if data[i] == "x":
        liste.append(x.next())
    else:
        x = itertools.count(2)
        liste.append(el)

return ",".join([str(x) for x in liste])
```

4 Use Blank down to clear duplicates

5 Split the first multivalued cell.

Here is a screencast of the operations described above.

[image]

If you know a little Python, you can also transform your file using `pandas`. I do not know what is the most elegant way to do it, but this script should work.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

x = itertools.count(2)

def set_x():
    global x
    x = itertools.count(2)

set_x()

def increase(value):

    if not value:
        return next(x)
    else:
        set_x()
        return value

data = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", na_values=['nan'], keep_default_na=False)


data['column 1'] = data['column 1'].apply(lambda row: increase(row))

print(data)

data.to_csv("final_file.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you. The OpenRefine option above seems not to entirely do what I wanted. As far as I can tell it fills the values not with an increasing counter. For example, if I have 5 blank cells, I want them to be filled with 2,3,4,5,6 and not 1,2,3,1,2. I might just do it in Python or R as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @EduardGeist This is exactly what it does: the first cell x is replaced by a 2, the second by a 3, and so on. And the counter is reset to two each time a 1 appears, exactly as in your example.

Comment: Sorry, yes! Thank you for figuring this one out.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it works and if no better solution is provided.

Comment: Great answer, Ettore! There'll be an easier way with the unreleased OpenRefine version (not available on 3.4.1 yet). You will be able to use `cross()` to get the previous row, then this'll be just a matter of `if previousRow = 1 { return 2 } else { return previousRow + 1 }` (pseudocode). See https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/200#issuecomment-609570460

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple solutions using GREL.

### Use records

You could move the column to the beginning, telling OpenRefine to use the numbers as records. You might need to transform the column to text to really convince OpenRefine to use it as records.
Then either add a new column or transform the existing one with the following expression.

```
1 + row.index - row.record.fromRowIndex
```

### Use record markers

In case you don't want to use records or don't have a static number, you can create a similar setup. Imagine you have an incomplete counter like in the following table and want to fill it.

| Origin | Desired |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
|  | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |

To fill the missing cells first add a new column based on your orignal column using the following expression and name it *record_row_index*.

```
if(isNonBlank(value), row.index, "")
```

After that [fill down](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#fill-down-and-blank-down) the original column and the new column *record_row_index*.

Then create a new column based on the original filled column using the following expression.

```
value + row.index - cells["record_row_index"].value
```

**Hint:** the expression is expecting both columns to be of type number.
If one of them is of type text, you can either transform the column beforehand or use [toNumber()](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#tonumbers) in the expression.

The following table shows how these operations are working together.

| Origin | Origin filled | row.index | record_row_index | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | `1 + 0 - 0 = 1` |
|  | 1 | 1 | 0 | `1 + 1 - 0 = 2` |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | `1 + 2 - 2 = 1` |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | `2 + 3 - 3 = 2` |
|  | 2 | 4 | 3 | `2 + 4 - 3 = 3` |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 | `1 + 5 - 5 = 1` |