# Add consecutive numbers to collection titles in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I am working on migrating a digital collection to another system that requires unique titles for each object. Is there a way in OpenRefine to add consecutive numbers in a column?
As an example:
Data currently reads as:

```
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01;
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01;
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01
```

I would like to automate adding the numbering sequence and have it read:

```
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (1);
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (2);
View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In OpenRefine we have a concept called [records](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records). You can use them to add counters to groups of data as described in the answers to [OpenRefine: Fill down with increasing counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348425/openrefine-fill-down-with-increasing-counter/68681794#68681794).

Here are the necessary steps:

1. Assuming you already have the data in columns and sorted (see column "Original" in the table below).
2. Move the column to the beginning.
3. Blank down the column to generate records (see column "Records").
4. Use the expression `row.record.cells[row.columnNames[0]][0].value + " (" +(1 + row.index - row.record.fromRowIndex) + ")"` to add a new column based on the first column or to transform the first column (see column "Transformed").

| Original | Records | Transformed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (1) |
| View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 |  | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (2) |
| View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 |  | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-01 (3) |
| View of Broad Street, 1999-01-02 | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-02 | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-02 (1) |
| View of Broad Street, 1999-01-02 |  | View of Broad Street, 1999-01-02 (2) |